# Is there any evolutionary significance of downward facing nostrils in human beings?

Tags: evolution, human-anatomy, human-evolution

The nostrils in apes and monkeys are *almost* at the front, but in humans nostrils (external nares) face downwards. Also a lot of non-primate mammals like goats have nostrils at the front.

Is it the increased cranial capacity in humans which pushed the nostrils downwards?

Is having a pair of downward facing nostrils, an advanced feature? If yes, then why?

Comment: I think you're right, there's a lot of articles here: https://www.google.fr/search?q=evolution+of+human+nose&oq=evolution+of+human+nose&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3832j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Some people do have quite upturned nostrils, it seems that dust, aridity, cold, long distance running, checking food, swimming, diving, and talking to people who have caught a cold are good reasons to have discreet nostrils and longer nares.